# set correctly routing in Symfony to have correct url and route

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, url, routes

I use **Symfony 2.5** (latest version) for create a web application. I work with **WAMP local server on windows 7**.

When I **lauch** the application, this is the **url** I get `http://localhost/Symfony/web/`. In fact I would like to add **/homepage**.

I have the first bundle named *WelcomeBundle* with his controller: It concerns my application **homepage**: `Gir/WelcomeBundle/Controller/HomePageController.php`

```
<?php

namespace Gir\WelcomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is the **routing file**: `Gir/WelcomeBundle/Ressource/config/routing.yml`

```
GirWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
  pattern:  /
  defaults: { _controller: GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index }
  requirements:
    methods: GET
    schemes:  https
```

And this is the **general routing file**: `app/config/routing.yml`

```
GirWelcomeBundle:
    resource: "@GirWelcomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

gir_administration:
    resource: "@GirAdministrationBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

gir_user:
    resource: "@GirUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

So when I arrive **first** on the application, I have my **HomePage**, so it works perfectly. This is the **url** when I lauch the application: `http://localhost/Symfony/web/`

But if I want to **add a path** like this (I add **/homepage** on the path line): `Gir/WelcomeBundle/Ressource/config/routing.yml`

```
GirWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
  pattern:  /homepage
  defaults: { _controller: GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index }
  requirements:
    methods: GET
    schemes:  https
```

The application doesn't **find the route**, I have this error:

```
No route found for "GET /" (from "http://localhost/Symfony/")
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

Someone know why?

Then, when I'm trying to lauch the **administration** page, the browser show me that the page is an **unreachable web page** like [this](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news-700/Chrome-Adds-an-quot-Offline-Cache-quot-Mode-to-Access-Unreachable-Pages.png).

I don't really understand. 
The bundle is named **AdministrationBundle**, this the **controller** code: `Gir/AdministrationBundle/Controller/AdministrationController.php`

```
<?php

namespace Gir\AdministrationBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AdministrationController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('GirAdministrationBundle:Admin:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And this the **routing file**: `Gir/AdministrationBundle/Ressource/config/routing.yml`

```
gir_administration_homepage:
    pattern:  /administration
    defaults: { _controller: GirAdministrationBundle:Administration:index }
    requirements:
    methods: GET
    schemes:  https
```

Someone could help me and explain me why?

Update post:
this the .htacess in web folder

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On


    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you set the virtual host up properly?  
E.g DocumentRoot /var/www/gir.dev/web  
Also is mod_rewrite enabled with the correct .htaccess?

Comment: I have updated my post and so you can see my htaccess code.

Comment: What about your virtual host settings?

Comment: @Rooneyl, i don't create yet a virtualhost, how it works exactly?

Answer (score 1):

By your description, I guess your `routing.yml` looked something like this:

```
GirWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index }
    requirements:
        methods: GET
        schemes:  https

GirWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
    pattern:  /homepage
    defaults: { _controller: GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index }
    requirements:
        methods: GET
        schemes:  https
```

The problem with this approach is that your `GirWelcomeBundle_HomePage`. Solution is simple:
Name routes differently, eg: `GirWelcomeBundle_Root` and `GirWelcomeBundle_Home`.

Also viable soultion would be to just define it in a single route:

```
GirWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
    pattern:  /{homepage}
    defaults: { _controller: GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index, homepage: 'homepage' }
    requirements:
        methods: GET
        schemes:  https
```

Comment: It's the same problem. I change my code like you suggest me but it still not working.

Comment: @Julien Are you in dev environment? If not, clear cache. `php app/console ca:c --env=prod`

Comment: I have already clear the cache, and nothing has changed. And I am sure that I am in dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your route back to **/homepage**, check `php app/console router:debug`-output and you'll see that there is no route for / but one for /homepage.

So you need another controller/route pair to redirect from / to /homepage.